# Unable to center layout in android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to center the relative layout inside linear layout. But I'm unable to do it. This is my complete code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Profile" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical">

     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/erected"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/population"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/year"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/pop"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/sun"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="@string/team"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="@string/francis"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:text="@string/lincoln"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anything wrong I'm doing in the code..?? I also tried **android:layout_gravity="center"** but its not working..Please suggest me where I'm going wrong..

Comment: what are the values of your padding? can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: because your relative layout is match_parent. make it wrap_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the textviews you can specify following,

```
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout changed little bit...

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Profile" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/profile"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/erected"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/population"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="@string/year"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:text="@string/pop"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="@string/sun"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="@string/team"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                android:text="@string/francis"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:text="@string/lincoln"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change width of relative layout to wrap_content and width of linear layout to match_parent. Then for relative layout use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change Gravity of your LinearLayout from:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

To

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

**EDIT:**
See this code I have implemented:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Profile" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="profile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="erected"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="population"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:text="@string/year"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                    android:text="pop"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="sun"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                    android:text="address"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="team"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                    android:text="francis"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                    android:text="lincoln"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It works fine for me.